# Which access right does 0x10000000 stand for in OpenMutex()?

Tags: c, windows, winapi

I see in a piece of code:

```
HANDLE handle = OpenMutex(0x10000000, false, L"NameOfMutexObject");
```

The call seems to be successful since I get a valid handle back (the return value is not NULL). But when I check in the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/sync/synchronization-object-security-and-access-rights) for what permissions this 0x10000000 bitmask stands for, I can't find it.

So, my question is: if `dwDesiredAccess = 0x10000000` then which access rights are granted?

I've tried it with a minimal example:

```
void testing_mutex() {
    HANDLE hMutex;

    hMutex = CreateMutex(
        NULL,                        // default security descriptor
        FALSE,                       // mutex not owned
        TEXT("NameOfMutexObject")
    );

    HANDLE mhandle = OpenMutex(0x10000000, false, L"NameOfMutexObject");
    if (mhandle == NULL || mhandle == 0)
    {
        printf("OpenMutex error: %d\n", GetLastError());
        return;
    }
    printf("MY MUTEX HANDLE: %d\n", mhandle);
}

int main(void)
{
    testing_mutex();
}
```

Comment: In *what* code do you "see" that `OpenMutex` call? Where did you the code from? Who gave it to you? Can that person, or a possible project maintainer, perhaps answer that?

Comment: "Only the SYNCHRONIZE access right is required to use a mutex." From which I read that the `SYNCHRONIZE` access right must be specified at a minimum. `SYNCHRONIZE` is `0x00100000L`. As this bit wasn't set, the value provided does not appear valid. And seeing as how `0x10000000` is `SYNCHRONIZE` with two extra zeroes, a good assumption is that this is a typo for the value of `SYNCHRONIZE`.

Comment: I tried a minimal example to see what happens, and it appears to be successful and gives a hande back, I've posted the sample code I used.

Comment: My comment is not affected by that.

Comment: If its a typo for the value of SYNCHRONIZE then how can this call not fail?

Comment: Easily. By not checking. Checking extra bits in a bitmask is often a needless waste of time. And not checking for `SYNCHRONIZE` which must always be provided could be considered the same. Try with just `0`...

Comment: With 0 the returned handle is 0 and GetLastError gives 5  ERROR_ACCESS_DENIED. But it might be that it is something in this direction mentioned by you.

Comment: `#define GENERIC_ALL (0x10000000L)`

Comment: I was wondering if this flag also is meaned to be used for mutex access rights. I can not find a source who explicitly says it but I think you are right, I found a code snipped where `OpenMutex` was called with `GENERIC_EXECUTE`, If you want you can create a answer and I will accept it

Comment: `GENERIC_ALL` can be used on **any** object. because this is generic. every object have own [`GENERIC_MAPPING`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winnt/ns-winnt-generic_mapping). for mutant this is translated to `MUTEX_ALL_ACCESS` (MUTEX_MODIFY_STATE + some standard access rights)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [*Access Mask Format*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/secauthz/access-mask-format):

[image: Access Mask Format]

> ... the 4 high-order bits are used to specify **[generic access rights](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/secauthz/generic-access-rights)** that each object type can map to a set of standard and object-specific rights.

and from *winnt.h*:

```
#define GENERIC_ALL                      (0x10000000L)
```

So the following code

```
HANDLE mhandle = OpenMutex(GENERIC_ALL, false, L"NameOfMutexObject");
```

means opening a mutex object with all possible access rights (mapped to `GENERIC_ALL`).

Comment: Also see [Generic Access Rights](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/secauthz/generic-access-rights). And this is exactly the kind of situation why the use of ["magic numbers"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_number_(programming)) in code is discouraged. If the author had just written `GENERIC_ALL` instead of `0x10000000` in the first place, there would not have been any confusion.